# Is there any way to pop all list items from redis list at once?

Tags: python-2.7, redis

I want to pop all list items from redis list at once.

I don't want to call `lpop` or `rpop` method by when the list is empty because it seems to be inefficient sending requests multi-time to `redis-server`.

I also know that I can get all lists with `lrange` method but not popping items.

Could you suggest me?

I just want to `pop` and `get` items in a list by one request to `redis-server`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Itamar Haber said, use lrange and del. In pipe mode it will be done as a single command.

```
LRANGE key 0 -1
DEL key
```

Comment: This seems to create a race condition when other processes are pushing to the list. e.g. the list gets an item added in between redis executing `LRANGE` and `DEL` by another application/process.

Comment: No, if these commands sent in PIPE mode. Or you can use MULTI & EXEC.

Comment: Redis pipelining is not atomic.

Answer (score 5):

Redis doesn't have an `POPALL` command, but with an embedded Lua script you can easily do that like this for example:

```
local reply = redis.call('LRANGE', KEYS[1], 0, -1)
redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1])
return reply
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
RENAME key key_processing
LRANGE key_processing 0 -1
DEL key_processing
```

This way we pop all the items and still maintain the original key "empty" but anyone can write/push a new element to the key list (for future processing)

Answer (score 1):

As of **redis 6.2.0**, you can lpop 'count' from key.

```
LPOP KEY N
```

This will pop **N** elements from **KEY**. You can use **LLEN** to count the length of list

```
LLEN KEY
```

Using redis pipeline and combining these two commands will pop all elements in a single command.